# Read content of MS Windows shortcut from within VirtualBox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, symlink, vagrant

I have setup (using vagrant) a VirtualBox machine with a shared directory. I can read text files from the `/media/sf_vagrant` just fine.

However I cannot `cat` the content of a file that I can only access via a `MS Windows shortcut`:

```
$ file /media/sf_vagrant/my_text.lnk
/media/sf_vagrant/my_text.lnk: MS Windows shortcut, Item id list present, Points to a file or directory, Has Relative path, Has Working directory, Archive, ctime=Thu Feb 15 13:30:29 2018, mtime=Thu Feb 15 13:30:29 2018, atime=Wed Feb 21 11:02:27 2018, length=24457, window=hide
```

From my windows OS, I can however double-click on `my_text.lnk` and notepad++ display the content (ASCII text file).

Is there a way to access the content of a file using a MS Windows shortcut from my VirtualBox ?

Comment: This seems more a failure on understanding Windows concepts, which turns it borderline off-topic in "Unix & Linux"; nonetheless I left an answer.

Comment: I believe the format of these files is described in the [MS-SHLLINK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305.aspx) page. Click on the pdf link to get the latest 48 page definition.

Answer (score 0):

The function of a Windows shortcut is pointing to a file that is on other location from the Windows point of view; so unless the file also lives in the shared directory, you cannot even see it from the Linux point of view.

Obviously Windows binaries can see and open it, as from their point of view, they understand Windows shortcuts and are able to see and access the whole Windows filesystem.

If you want to see the file from Linux, the easiest solution is to move the file the Windows shortcut points to, to the shared directory and access it directly.